# How to make hours and minutes of Swift's DateComponents comparable if not this way?

Tags: swift, algorithm, swift-extensions

## Abstract

The requirements of the app I'm working on make me use `DateComponents` as a bridge when working with time - specifically hours and minutes. Another requirement made me make `DateComponents: Comparable` and that's when I found some nasty behavior, I can't explain.

### The idea

For the sake of the argument, assume that there is a component in which the user may choose the hour of his liking. He can either pick a pre-defined time of tweak it.
As app's interface needs to react to changes, it shall pick the enum closest to the hour set.

#### Enum

```
enum TimeOfDay: String {
    case morning
    case evening
}
```

#### Extension with function

```
extension TimeOfDay {
    private static let morningHours =
        DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0)...DateComponents(hour: 15, minute: 00)
    
    static func appropriateTimeOfDay(for time: DateComponents) -> Self {
        var timeOfDay: Self?
        if morningHours.contains(time) {
            timeOfDay = .morning
        } else {
            timeOfDay = .evening
        }
        return timeOfDay!
    }
}
```

### The problem

Since I want to use `func contains(_ element: Bound) -> Bool`, my `Bound`, being `DateComponents`, must conform to `Comparable`. I took a sheet of paper, ran some examples through it, and this implementation seemed pretty reasonable.

In my code I made sure that the `DateComponents.hour` and `DateComponents.minute` are never `nil` wherever they should be compared, hence forced unpacking.

#### Comparable extension

```
 extension DateComponents: Comparable {
     public static func < (lhs: DateComponents, rhs: DateComponents) -> Bool {
         return lhs.hour! < rhs.hour! || lhs.minute! < rhs.minute!
     }
 }
```

However, I ran into problems. The tests shown that, although the `contains` worked on full hours in range, **the time was not contained in range whenever minutes came into play.**

#### Test

Sample test for those to wish to check it themselves.

```
func testDateComponentsWithMinutesContainedInRange() {
    let range = DateComponents(hour: 0, minute: 0)...DateComponents(hour: 15, minute: 0)
    let hours = [
        DateComponents(hour: 00, minute: 1),
        DateComponents(hour: 12, minute: 30),
        DateComponents(hour: 14, minute: 59),
    ]
    
    // conditions for ClosedRange.contains
    // all passed
    for hour in hours {
        XCTAssert(range.lowerBound < hour)
        XCTAssert(hour < range.upperBound)
        XCTAssertNotEqual(hour, range.lowerBound)
        XCTAssertNotEqual(hour, range.upperBound)
    }
    
    // ClosedRange.contains
    for time in hours {
        XCTAssert(range.contains(time), "failed for \(time.hour!):\(time.minute!)")
    }
}
```

### The solution

After a few good hours of scratching my head, I've found [this wonderful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64516065/12938809) that solved the problem. Code, for the convenience of readers, pasted below.

```
// [post][1]
// [author][2]
extension DateComponents: Comparable {
    public static func < (lhs: DateComponents, rhs: DateComponents) -> Bool {
        let now = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        return calendar.date(byAdding: lhs, to: now)! < calendar.date(byAdding: rhs, to: now)!
    }
}
```

My question remains - **what was wrong with my attempt?** I was interested in checking the hours and minutes of `DateComponents` only, and those are both `Int?`.
My wild guess is that the fact that the minute has 60 (effectively, 59) seconds made the comparator in `contains` go bonkers.

Comment: I'm glad that you answered your question! I know it feels weird, but I would suggest not editing the question to include your solution, but rather revert the question back to its original form and just [post a separate answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). You can eventually mark your own answer as “accepted”, removing this question from the list of open/unresolved questions. This preserves the Q&A format of this forum. Or, if you don't want to do that, you can also just click on “close” on this question, selecting that other answer as the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your extension makes no sense.

Consider this example:

```
let lhs = DateComponents(hour: 13, minute: 2)
let rhs = DateComponents(hour: 12, minute: 12)

print(lhs < rhs)
```

That prints true, even though 13:02 is clearly after (aka greater than) 12:12.

You would have to do math to calculate a total number of minutes and compare those minutes values. For hours and minutes that manual calculation wouldn't be too bad, but when you get into days, weeks, and months, it gets messy. (How many days in a month? Which month? How many days in a year? Is it a leap year?)

Adding dateComponents to some date does make at least some sense. When you add 2 different sets of date components to a fixed date, the resulting Date (which is Comparable) will be greatest when you add a DateComponents object that describes the longest span of time.

Bear in mind that adding components to a Date has gotchas as well, depending on what units you are working with, and the date you use as your "base date". (e.g. I add a month to the current date. How many days is that? Depends. Is it February, with 29 Days, or January, with 31 days?)